# Java Regex looking a combination of words in any order

Tags: regex, string, find, any

I'm looking for a way to find two or more words in a sentence that might come in any order.  For example I might look for the words "NCAA" and "Basketball" in a sentence that says  NCAA Indiana Vs. Purdue Basketball" or it might say "Indiana Vs. Purdue Basketball NCAA".  How would I write the regex for the words showing in any order and any location in the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookahead:

```
(?=.*NCAA)(?=.*Basketball)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?=.*NCAA)`: Positive lookahead to assert presence of string  `NCAA` any where ahead of the current position
- `(?=.*Basketball)`: Positive lookahead to assert presence of string  `Basketball` any where ahead of the current position

Or else use alternation if your regex tool doesn't support lookaheads:

```
NCAA.*?Basketball|Basketball.*?NCAA
```

Comment: May I ask: how does two lookaheads match for "Indiana Vs. Purdue Basketball NCAA"

Comment: @BIBOOunit1998X: I have added explanation in my answer.