# regex pattern to match string in any order

Tags: java, regex

How to find first match of string `abc` in shuffled order using regex pattern in java?

Example:

input 1: abcbaa
input 2: bcbaaa
input 3: cbaaab

1st match for input 1 : **abc**baab
1st match for input 2 : b**cba**aab
1st match for input 3 : **bca**aabc

Patterns that I've tried that didn't work:

```
(?:([abc])(?!\\.*]\\1)){3}
(?!(.)\\1)[abc]{3}
```

The above 2 patterns matches 3 consecutive characters, including duplicate values.
example: ***aba**bac*
expected: *aba**bac***

```
(?=.*[abc])(?=.*[abc])(?=.*[abc])
```

This one matches and empty character in-between each character. i.e., string position (0,0), (1,1), (2,2) etc...

Comment: Please show some code. What have you tried so far? SO will not build solutions, but answer specific questions.

Comment: Go read some tutorials about regex, you will find what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Regex looking a combination of words in any order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041258/java-regex-looking-a-combination-of-words-in-any-order)

Comment: You might want to have a deeper look in the classes java.util.regex.Pattern and java.util.regex.Matcher

Comment: Something like [`([abc])(?!\1)([abc])(?!\1|\2)[abc]`](https://regex101.com/r/mO8lG5/1)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew ! pattern you mentioned was very useful and helped me in improving performance too. Thanks again.

Comment: @Others: Updated the question with the attempts I tried.

Comment: @Arun Instead of putting @ Others, you'd better write comments to everyone who posted comments so that they could reopen your question if they think your question qualifies. The patterns are not enough as you should state what problems you have when using them.

Comment: Updated the question with the attempts I tried.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks again! updated the question.

Comment: Good, perhaps, this question will get reopened now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to look of all the possibilities? Something like this with your example:

```
(abc|acb|bca|bac|cab|cba)
```

Comment: This solution event if it is simple doesn't really give you the best performance (factorial(n) complexity)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this regex:

```
^(?=[\s\S]*(a)+)(?=[\s\S]*(b)+)(?=[\s\S]*(c)+)[\s\S]*$
```

Comment: `(.|\s)*` is [extremely inefficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407870/javascript-regex-hangs-using-v8) and should never be used.  Instead, use Java's `DOTALL` flag, or add `(?s)` to the beginning of the regex.

Comment: Thank you, Alan.
Can I use [^]* instead of (.|\s)* ?

Comment: `[^]` is only useful in the JavaScript flavor, which doesn't have a DOTALL option (yet).  In Java it's a syntax error.  If you are using JavaScript, I recommend you use `[\s\S]` instead.  It's longer, but it works the same across flavors, and its meaning is more obvious (any whitespace character + any non-whitespace character = any character).

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:a()|b()|c()){3}\1\2\3
```

The empty groups act like check boxes, so if `\1\2\3` matches, each of the letters must have been seen at least once.  Since the regex only consumes three characters, you know there's exactly one of each letter.